# resizing Two UIViews one along other by changing UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, split

I'm trying to create an application (for ipad) that displays two views next to each others and resizable by `UISlider` just by changing Value from 0 to screen width ( 1024 ) just like this

[image]

width=512 which makes the main view split into two views one equal to other
my question is how to make those views resize-able by user with `UISlider` 
I tried this

`viewResizer` is `UISlider`

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    if (self.viewResizer.value >512) {
        [self.secView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.secView.frame.origin.x, self.secView.frame.origin.y,self.viewResizer.value , 660.0)];
        [self.firstView setFrame:CGRectMake(orgiX, orgiY,self.secView.frame.size.width- self.viewResizer.value , 660)];
    }else{

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Your slider would have 1024 values for example, then You could:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender 
{
    //First view will be resized from 0 to sliders value, 
    [self.firstView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sender.value, 660)];

    //Second view will be resized from first views width, to 1024(parent view width)-first views width.
    [self.secView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.firstView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - self.firstView.frame.size.width, 660)];
}
```

You could then decrease sliders values to 256 (but then it will not be as smooth):

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender 
{
    //First view will be resized from 0 to sliders value, 
    [self.firstView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sender.value*4, 660)];

    //Second view will be resized from first views width, to 1024(parent view width)-first views width.
    [self.secView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.firstView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - self.firstView.frame.size.width, 660)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help ! I really appreciate it ! but unfortunately it didn't help me ! do you have any idea or alternative way ? to fix this issue 

http://imgur.com/zaKM9V3 I used your second code and I changed the positions value to frame.origin.x and y

Comment: Hmm can You archive your project and send it to me?  gtreulands@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, I was too lazy to wait, so I cooked up a quick project (using xcode 5.0 + arc)  - just so You would see how it can be implemented.  http://failiem.lv/down.php?i=uchmcke&n=SliderTestProj.zip  (IPad, landscape only!)